# How do I view the clone properties of a snowflake database

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a database in snowflake using following command:

```
create database test_clone clone TEST;
```

Now I want to check all clone properties of database.
I am unable to find those properties in **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES**.

Please let me know how to find clone properties.

e.g. below property information for created database.

```
 [ CLONE <source_db>
          [ { AT | BEFORE } ( { TIMESTAMP => <timestamp> | OFFSET => <time_difference> | STATEMENT => <id> } ) ] ]
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "clone properties"? What do you want to see.

Answer (score 3):

There are no clone properties.  There is no concept of "a clone", only of the action of "cloning".   Once you have cloned a database, the "clone" is just a regular database.

You should be able to see the new database `test_clone` eg. in the list of databases in the Snowflake Web GUI, if you have access to it.  It should also appear in all *database*`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES` *if* you have access.

Please excuse me if I've misunderstood your question, I find the wording a little unconventional.